# On iPhone, layout with outer/inner DIV: get trapped in outer DIV when scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, iphone

I have the following layout issue. I have a mobile app with a 3-column layout. On selecting a certain section, appropriate sub-panels get shown/hidden.

The outer DIV is a scrollable DIV. Section 1 also has a scrollable inner DIV.

The problem is that when I activate Section 1, **the iPhone traps my scrolling in the outer DIV even though I'm pressing my thumb inside the inner DIV**, and I can't scroll my inner DIV, which is what I really want to do. So the user tries the scroll the actual inner DIV and instead they're scrolling the outer DIV which contains the Header, Section Area, and Footer (there's a little bit of a scrolling range there, just a little).

[image]

The goal is that upon returning to Section 1, if the user "thumbs" the Inner DIV, then the Inner DIV should get scrolled. But the Outer DIV gets scrolled "by default."

I've tried various things: Doing a `focus()` in JS whenever I activate Section 1; Putting `tabindex=0` on the Inner DIV to make it focusable. None of this worked.

I also tried making the Inner DIV's Height in % or Pixels. If I change it to Pixels (like 900px), I get out of some initial traps, but others still get introduced.

Basically I need this:

```
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {            
    if ($($(e.target)[0].closest('div')).attr('id') == 'innerDIV') {
        // We are inside the Inner DIV. 
        // Force scrolling inside this DIV; Disable any outer body scrolling
        $('body').css('overflow-y', 'hidden');
        // Or maybe $('#innerDIV').focus() ?
    } else {
        // Outside
        $('body').css('overflow-y', 'auto');                
    }

}, false);
```